# CSS Font Sizes Conflict

Tags: css, fonts, size

I have a question about CSS font sizes. I have a CSS code which species a line "There is not much on it" to be of font size 200%. But at the same time, I have specified the body of the text to have a font size of 12pt. When I change the font size of the body of the text to 8pt, the line "There is not much on it" becomes smaller! Surely changing the body font size should NOT override the font size of this particular line (which I have specifically asked to be 200%.) Can someone also please tell me what the new font size of this line is when I change the BODY font size to 8pt? Is it 200% * 8/12 = 133%. Is that how it works? I'm an absolute beginner.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <style>
    p.bigger{font-size:200%}
    p.smaller{font-size:10pt}
    #intro{color:red}
    body{font-size:12pt}
    p{color:blue; font:Arial, sans-serif}
    h1{color:green}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    <p id="intro">Welcome to my page</p>
    <p class="bigger">There is not much on it</p>
    <p class="smaller">Except this</p>
    <ul>
    <li>Short list</li>
    </ul>
    <h1 style="font-style:italic">Contact</h1>
    Here is my address
    </body>
    <html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilize `em` instead of `percentages` when setting font-sizes.

This is because the `em` value will inherit the `parent` value (in this case body).

So, something such as `font-size:2em` is equivalent to `200%` when compared to your `8px` or `12px`.

---

`body { font-size:8px; }`

`thisFontSize { font-size:2em; }`

`thisFontSize` will be equal to `16px`.

#### OR

`body { font-size:12px; }`

`thisFontSize { font-size:2em; }`

`thisFontSize` will be equal to `24px`.

---

If you need it to be `2em` larger than something other than `body`, you can define it as such. Play around with this fiddle, as it may make more sense.

#### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/7KR9t/

Comment: Well explained. Thanks, Nicholas.

Comment: Added fiddle for a solution to have it NOT use the `body` as it's comparison. If you feel this is an accepted answer, please mark it as such with the `green checkbox` by the voting arrows.

Comment: The JSFiddle site is definitely more user friendly than w3schools site. I've ticked you up, with thanks.

Comment: **w3schools sucks**... It's nice if you *already know it but need a reference*, but not so good for learning. Thanks for the vote.

Comment: From the original question, I thought the user didnt't want the size of thisFontSize to change when changing the body font size. How does using `em` solve the problem and how does it differ from `%` in this specific scenario? I'm confused.

Comment: Use a `parent element`. Look at the latest `fiddle`. It adapts its `2em` from it's parent `.item`.

Comment: @Nicholas: `200%` instead of `2em` also inherits the parent element font-size, no? [fiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/f7Dxr/). Taking your fiddle as an example, I think the OP didn't want the text size of "Hello" to change when changing the font size of **the parent element** (`.item` in this case - not necessarily body). Unless I'm getting this all wrong, if so, thanks for the patience.

Comment: First and foremost, never use percentages with your `css` when regarding `font-size`. You will have a bad time. Secondly, if you need a static size, just create some sort of element with a pre-defined `font-size`, even if it's not technically part of the `DOM` and just add the `class` that way.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly how it works though another way of writing it would be to use:

```
2em
```

which does the same thing as 200%

Answer (score 0):

A percentage is a relative value while pt/px is an absolute one. So, in your case, you get 200% of 12pt (24pt) or 200% of 8pt (16pt). So you should give an absolute value to `p.bigger`, eg. `p.bigger { font-size: 16pt }`, so when changing the body font-size, it will only affect elements with a percentage or elements which don't have a font-size assigned (`h1`, in your example). Remember that `body` contains all elements, it doesn't matter if it's after `h1` or `p` in your stylesheet, but it really should be at the beginning.

Also, consider using header tags for titles and subtitles instead of relying too much on different classes just for text size. Check [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/fccs0ma1) example.

Also take a look at [this](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) article concerning the available measurement units.

Answer (score -1):

When you use percentage in `font-size` value for an element, it'll refer to the parent element's font size value.

So parent element of your `.bigger` paragraph is `body` so the final `font-size` will be `8pt * 2 = 16pt`